# Spring Boot REST webservice endpoint when provided external Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have a simple java web application built with Spring Boot and Maven. Every time I modify my artifact version in the pom.xml my web service endpoint changes.

For example, assuming in the controller class I have @RequestMapping("/api/v1/") annotation and assuming the following pom excerpt

```
<artifactId>myConv</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

the webservice endpoint will be http://localhost/myConv-1.0.0/api/v1/....

If I change the version to 1.0.2 the endpoint wil be http://localhost/myConv-1.0.2/api/v1/....

How can I make it static ?

Thanks.

#### UPDATE

I've found the solution does not work, because the provided server (Wildfly) overrides the spring application context.

I've resolved the problem changing the context as specified [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIOverrideTheWebContextRoot).

But can someone explain me why ?

#### UPDATE 2 - solution when deploy on external server

I found this guide which seems to be nice https://octopus.com/blog/defining-tomcat-context-paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the context path property
`server.servlet.context-path=/` in your `application.yml` or in `application.properties` and you will be able to access REST api as
`http://localhost/api/v1/`.

Comment: I don't know why, it does not work if I deploy manually the war. Instead it seems to work if i launch trough the IDE. Does the pom.xml may be the cause ?

Comment: Unzip the war and check if it has updated property file. Also, before creating war do run `mvn clean` target. Another check point is, check if your `war` target is including all the property files you have created and putting them into war.

Comment: Yes, it does. The war contains the correct .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure

```
server.servlet.context-path
```

take a look at the official documentation
[spring boot documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path)